# Send a signal from child to parent application in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to give a signal to parent application, saying that the child application is moved his task to another 3rd party application,

Once method I found that make use of a cookies? Is there any other way.

** Should be some client side technique

Comment: What is the nature of the application? What signal are you trying to give? What have you tried so far?

Comment: parent and child are two asp.net web applications, Child application is used to redirecting (sso)

Comment: Your Question is incomplete, you need to give more info on it. if required even provide relevant code snippets or scenarios which you are talking abt.

Comment: If child and parent applications are individual web app`s , then u can pass the date between them via REQUEST line itself.

Comment: I have tried using a cookies, Add a cookie from SSO (child) application and frequently checking the cookie value from parent application. using JS, This issue is comming only when browser cookies are disable

Comment: I'm calling from parent to child and then child to 3rd party app (running on Iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Look up signalR it's going to be your best bet!

Comment: please elaborate the answer, see [answer]